# Makefile seems to take both inputs instead of one at a time

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have two files `1.gv` and `2.gv` which are Graphviz files.

I wrote this Makefile from what I could figure out:

```
DOT=dot
FORMAT=svg
SRC=$(wildcard *.gv)
OUT=$(subst .gv,.$(FORMAT),$(SRC))

all: $(OUT)

$(OUT): $(SRC)
    $(DOT) -T$(FORMAT) $^ -o $@

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f $(OUT)
```

The clean seems to work, the only problem seems to be is it runs:

```
dot -Tsvg 1.gv 2.gv -o 1.svg
dot -Tsvg 1.gv 2.gv -o 2.svg
```

instead of:

```
dot -Tsvg 1.gv -o 1.svg
dot -Tsvg 2.gv -o 2.svg
```

Comment: You need one rule to make one target.  This: `$(OUT): $(SRC)` expands to this: `1.svg 2.svg: 1.gv 2.gv`.  That is not one rule for one target.  Using a pattern rule, as below, will allow you to create one rule that matches any target with that pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Makefile make sees that it needs all gv-files (SRC) to make one file: 1.gv (OUT) so in the loop the prerequisite changes *$<* but not the target *$@*.
You need to match a pattern and use [`patsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) instead of `subst` so OUT is a pattern of files.

I removed most variables for clarity. Feel free to add them back.

```makefile
SRC = $(wildcard *.gv)
OUT = $(patsubst %.gv,%.svg,$(SRC))

%.svg: %.gv
    dot -Tsvg $< -o $@

all: $(OUT)

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) *.svg
```

Comment: Ah. I thought I was close with `$<`. I have noticed though this gives me `Makefile:5: *** missing separator.` I looked at [`patsubst`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html) and the use of that function looks fine. Hmm.

Comment: You need to be sure the recipe line begins with a TAB character not spaces.  A google of that error message will give you 1,000's of hits.

Comment: Ah of course.... it's been a while since I've worked with GNU Make and I forgot about that.